# Swift OAuth2.0 with redirectURI

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, swiftui, token

I'm using a service that provides an OAuth2.0 authentication. This are the steps i need:

- Open a URL with user Id as params
- User approves my app (which is correctyle registered).
- The user is redirected to a RedirectUri, with access token in the hash.

The third point is my main problem.

I've implemented the OAuth with microsoft libraries and everything works fine. But I cant use them here so I'm trying https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift this one.

This is my code:

```
private func authenticationService() {
    // create an instance and retain it
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    "xx",
        consumerSecret: "xxx",
        authorizeUrl:   "//myurl + userId",
        responseType:   "token"
    )

    oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = OAuthSwiftOpenURLExternally.sharedInstance

    let handle = oauthswift.authorize(
        withCallbackURL: "???",
        scope: "", state:"") { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let (credential, response, parameters)):
          print(credential.oauthToken)
          // Do your request
        case .failure(let error):
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

This open correctly my Safari but then I'm redirected to the URI with access token in the hash and nothing happened.

The main problem here is that I've a redirect uri so I guess the callback URL is not called? And this is not opening a sheet but it is redirecting to Safari. And I dont like this approach.

How can I perform OAuth2.0 in swift with the steps above? How can I get the access token from an url? What is the best library and how can I get the most of it?

---

Update:

This is my code for stackExchange:

```
    let request: OAuth2Request = .init(authUrl: "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=<MYCLIENTID>&scope=private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success",
                                   tokenUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json",
                                   clientId: "<MYCLIENTID>",
                                   redirectUri: "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success",
                                   clientSecret: "",
                                   scopes: [])
```

The OAuth domain in stack apps is => stackexchange.com
So i've added in my URL Types the following: redirect-uri://<stackexchange.com> (even without <>)

But everytimes I approve my app i'm stacked in the "Authorizing application" which contains my token and i'm not redirected.

Comment: This is a good question, i'm gonna link a new lib take a look =>

Comment: Try this from this good tutorial!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 13 you can use the new AuthenticationServices library provided by Apple.

It will work on both macOS and iOS.

Maybe this would help other developers, I create a simple and small swift package to handle OAuth2 in Swift, you can check the demo project it works very well

https://github.com/hadiidbouk/SimpleOAuth2

**Edit:**

You are passing the wrong URLs, they should be like this

```swift
let request: OAuth2Request = .init(authUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth",
                                       tokenUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json",
                                       clientId: "<<your client id>>",
                                       redirectUri: "redirect-uri://stackexchange.com",
                                       clientSecret: "<<your client secret>>",
                                       scopes: ["private_info"])
```

Comment: This is super interesting, I'm trying this. I'm trying to implement OAuth with StackExchange, but I really cant figure out how to do it. I'm adding all the info required but once the "Authorize" page prompr and I click it, i'm redirected to a new page and I'm not able to close the "authentication sheet" in order to get the token. Have you tried with StackExchange? I would really appreciate any kind of help

Comment: I tried GitLab only, will try StackExchange and get back to you 

Comment: It's working now, you can use the 1.0.4 version of the package, I change the OAuth2Credentials struct to the one defined in RFC 6749 OAuth 2.0 tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.1. StackExchange is returning "expires" but the recommended one is "expires_in", so I handle this in the new version. PS: For redirecting you need to register your scheme in target>info>URL Types. Something like "redirect-uri://<<your domain on stackApps>>" will works. Tell me if it's working for you now and if I need to edit the library, I am always opened for modification since I am using it in my apps

Comment: Also don't forget to use the JSON format of the access token response "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json"

Comment: you are so kind. I really appreciate your help and ill share your library. But i'm still facing the issue, I updated my answer with all the details. You tried the StackExchange Oauth right? And i'ts working? Is there anything different between my update and your code?

Comment: I think the problem is the redirectUri in URL Types, because the whole process might be fine but its not redirecting back to my app.

Comment: Updated my answer, I hope that it's clear for you now.

Comment: THIS IS GREAT. Finally i have a wroking Oauth. May I ask one more question? Once I have "credentials" i see I can save them or load them but how do I acess "access token" specifically?

Comment: Please feel free to contact me by email, this isn’t the right place

Answer (score 1):

In the below code:

```
private func authenticationService() {
    // create an instance and retain it
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(...)
```

you don't *retain* `oauthswift` (nor `handle`). They will be deallocated as soon as you finish executing the `authenticationService` function.

You need to store references to `oauthswift` and `handle` outside the function (at the class level).

```
let oauthswift: OAuth2Swift
let handle: ...

init() {
    oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    "xx",
        consumerSecret: "xxx",
        authorizeUrl:   "//myurl + userId",
        responseType:   "token"
    )
    ...
}

private func authenticationService() {
    handle = oauthswift.authorize(...)
}
```

Comment: This is a good point, i didnt noticed that.
But this is what happend => I tap my button => redirect to Safari => I log in and im readirected to a page with the access code in hash. But nothing happend in my code, safari is not dismissed, the UX is not good and I dont have token.

In "withCallBackURL i'm adding my bundleIdentifier + :/oauth2Callback

Comment: I have my redirect uri inside authorizeUrl and when I'm redirected I have accessToken in this url